# How can i apply this blur effect on my website

Tags: html, css

How do I apply [this soft shadow effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf0aq.png) underneath the horizontal purple. rows, I want to use this effect on my website. I used the box-shadow but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any blur or shadow on the example you linked.

Comment: Perhaps he means the slightly darker horizontal line that separates the two tones of purple.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Edited the post to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could imitate the effect in your sample image.

[image]

Here is what I did.

#### HTML

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#outer{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:#383142;
}
#inner{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background:#514762;
    box-shadow:0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, and make sure to mark the answer if it helped!